# Our home is lost, are we too?

Tags: alternate-history

A girl had a vision,she's a close friend of my wife and she told everyone that the village will be destroyed. The lands will open and people will fall into the abyss, those surviving will be burned alive by falling fire under dark clouds of death. The only way to get out alive is to escape as far as possible from our home island.

Our family and some other people decided to believe her, the rest of the village didn't want to abandon their homes. We are 16 people, 11 of us are women and young girls. I and the rest are man, one is a child, a young boy.

We sold everything we had and bought a boat, and food. A slow vessel but the Oracle girl has learned some basic magic powers, by putting her hand into water she can somehow push the boat to go faster, up to 20 knots it seems.

The world is unknown to us,our village had no maps,all we know is that not too far and not too close to our native isle there's the empire of Japan,we know them because some of their merchants visited us once many years ago, they stayed for some time and told us stories about their land and their new Emperor. But all we want is to find a safe place to live in, and maybe other cities.

How long could it take to find land with other people, or is it more likely that we will perish lost into the sea? Our oracle can't see the future at will, but she has random visions.

Comment: It seems you're trying to tell a story here rather than build a world. The answer as to whether you're lost at sea is best answered by your Oracle rather than navigational skills.

Comment: A world is made of living things, and all of them have a story... a world without stories to tell is merely a floating rock.  Anyway, seriously... this was a dream of mine this morning and I was simply curious to see if we had any chance to survive.

Comment: So the question is ‘starting from near Japan, how long will it take to reach a civilised country if we set off in a random direction’? We need to know how near japan you are, if Japan is being swallowed up too and what time period you’re in (civilisations aren’t a constant).

Comment: The answer seems to depend entirely on chance, whether they set off on the right direction or happenstance brought them there. And all things that depend on probability are controlled by you as the writer. Note that the characters themselves are completely unsure how far the land is, if there is any. The oracle may decide she's had enough of pushing herself to carry them all, while being just a few miles off mainland. These things lead to interesting plot points.

Comment: As you write your story, remember to define "civilisation", as an island tribe if they have no knowledge of navigation then they have no knowledge of cities. They would merely be looking for an unoccupied patch of land to build a new village rather than looking for other people.

Comment: There's a simple formular to check if this works: Its called basic maths.   
You have 20 knots speed and you can survive for [food amount] days, so you can travel around speed * time = distance  
when you calculate a bit of missdirection, you have to travel a bit more
when you calculate your group can even starve for some days to survive you can come even farer. I have heard people can survive up to two days without water => meaning: 10 (m/s) * 2 (d) * 24 (h) * 60 (min) * 60 (s) = 1.728.000 (m) without even food or water. That is almost as long as Japan in whole

Comment: It depends where you are relative to Japan and the direction of prevailing currents and prevailing winds. If they are both against you, even 20 knots won't help. In terms of sea currents, you could spend days going nowhere without even realising it.

Comment: Given that you're not in regular contact with Japan, you're not on the home islands. For similar reasons, you're probably not in the Sea of Japan either, or you'd have met the Chinese or Koreans. You are most likely somewhere in the middle of the Pacific, but whether you are in the Philippines, Midway or Guam is up to you and where you want to take your story